# How can I write a subroutine for DBI updates with varying number of arguments?

Tags: perl, dbi

I'm writing a subroutine for DBI updates, and are having some trouble figuring out how to add placeholder and stuff...

I have this:

```
sub row_update {
  my $table = shift;
  my %updates = @_;
  my $placeholders = ...

  $dbh->do("UPDATE $table SET (foo) WHERE (bar)") etc...
}
```

Any ideas?

I just want a simple update function where I can send in x number of arguments (as a hash).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, it sounds like you're after [SQL::Abstract](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SQL::Abstract).  First, we create an `SQL::Abstract` object:

```
use SQL::Abstract;
my $sql = SQL::Abstract->new;
```

Now, as an example, we'll use it to insert some data into a table:

```
my %record = (
    FirstName  => 'Buffy',
    LastName   => 'Summers',
    Address    => '1630 Revello Drive',
    City       => 'Sunnydale',
    State      => 'California',
    Occupation => 'Student',
    Health     => 'Alive',
);

my ($stmt, @bind) = $sql->insert(’staff’,\%record);
```

This results in:

```
$stmt = "INSERT INTO staff
                (FirstName, LastName, Address, City,
                 State, Occupation, Health)
                 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

@bind = ('Buffy','Summers','1630 Revello Drive',
         'Sunnydale',’California','Student','Alive');
```

The nice thing about this is we can pass it directly to DBI:

```
 $dbh->do($stmt, undef, @bind);
```

Of course, you want to be updating records, not just inserting them.  Luckily, this is also quite easy:

```
my $table = 'People';

my %new_fields = (
    Occupation => 'Slayer',
    Health     => 'Dead',
);

my %where = (
    FirstName => 'Buffy',
    LastName  => 'Summers',
);

my ($stmt, @bind) = $sql->update($table, \%new_fields, \%where);

$dbh->do($stmt, undef, @bind);
```

This produces:

```
$stmt = 'UPDATE People SET Health = ?, Occupation = ? 
         WHERE ( FirstName = ? AND LastName = ? )';

@bind = ('Dead', 'Slayer', 'Buffy', 'Summers');
```

If you're after more information about `SQL::Abstract`, I recommend you look at its [CPAN page](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SQL::Abstract).  There's also a chapter in [Perl Training Australia](http://perltraining.com.au/)'s *Database Programming with Perl* manual, which are freely available from our [course notes page](http://perltraining.com.au/notes.html).

All the best,

*Paul*

Disclaimer: I'm managing director of Perl Training Australia, and therefore think that our course notes are pretty good.

Comment: Minor issue: You've got different quote marks around 'student' in the first '@bind = ...', which is buggering up the syntax colouring

Answer (score 4):

Something like this might be Good Enough:

```
sub update {
    my ($dbh, $args) = @_;

    my $table   = $args->{table}   || die 'need table';
    my $updates = $args->{updates} || die 'need updates';

    my @cols = keys %$updates;

    my $query = 'UPDATE $table SET '.
      (join ', ', map { '$_ = ?' } @cols)
      ($args->{where} ? ' WHERE '. $args->{where} : '');

    my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);

    $sth->execute(map { $updates->{$_} } @cols);

    return $sth;
}
```

Use it like:

```
my $sth = update $dbh, {
    table   => 'foo',
    updates => {
        col1 => 'new_value',
        col2 => 'another_value',
    },
    where => 'id=42',
};
```

Really, though, you want to look into using an ORM like
[DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx::Class).  It will do a much better job of building queries than
string manipulation like this will.

(Rewriting the where clause to be parameterized is left as an exercise to the reader.  You also need to quote the update keys and table name.  See why people use ORMs?)

Edit: Thinking about this a bit more, you might like [DBIx::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx::Simple) combined with [SQL::Abstract](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SQL::Abstract).  This will take less configuration effort than an ORM, but still give you many of the benefits.

Comment: I think you might be missing a comma in your join string around line 10, didn't you mean something like join(q{, }, map... ), to join the field=value pairs using commas?

Answer (score 1):

Others suggested the usual "build a query with the right number of '?'s" approach.

For most queries like this the DBI->quote method is forgotten, but it can keep the code simpler and in most cases it's not any slower than the "proper" placeholder approach.

1) Use DBI->quote instead of place holders to build the query.  For example for a simple select:

```
my $sql = "select foo from bar where baz in ("
           . join(",", map { DBI->quote($_) } @bazs)
           . ")";
my $data = $dbh->selectall_arrayref($sql);
```

2) As jrockway suggested - use an ORM to do this sort of low level stuff for you.  DBIx::Class or Rose::DB::Object, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The `NUM_OF_PARAMS` attribute may be of assistance:

```
"NUM_OF_PARAMS"  (integer, read-only)
     The number of parameters (placeholders) in the prepared
     statement.
```

So for instance, I've got a script to run arbitrary SQL from the command line that uses this code:

```
my $s = $h->prepare($_);

for my $i (1..$s->{NUM_OF_PARAMS}){
  my $param = shift @ARGV;
  $s->bind_param($i, $param);
  print LOG "Bind param $i using $param.\n"
    or die "can't append to $opt{log}: $!";
}

$s->execute();
```

I can't say I've used the other modules that have been suggested, so they may do a better job.